# Maybe and recursion on list

Tags: haskell

I try to implement the `reverse` function with `Maybe`. I don't know how to return `Just` in pattern matching using recursion. By example, `ghci> myReverse [1,2,3]` need to return `Just [3,2,1]`. Here is my code :

```
myReverse :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
myReverse [] = Nothing
myReverse [x] = Just [x]
myReverse (x:xs) = myReverse xs ++ [x] -- here's my problem.
```

I thought that `myReverse (x:xs) = Just $ myReverse xs ++ [x]` work, but no and I don't know how to do it. What I would to know it is how to do it and why.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not implementing the same behavior as the original `reverse` function?  Why can't the reverse of an empty list be an empty list?

Comment: Yeah it can be, but the goal is to learn more about Haskell (to be confronted at this kind of problem force you to try a lot of solutions and searching for answers,  and so you learn new things).

Answer (score 5):

`myReverse` returns a `Maybe [a]`, which can't be directly appended to something because it is not a list.  IOW the value of `myReverse xs` will be either `Nothing`, or `Just <some list>`.  You need to pattern match on the result.

```
myReverse (x:xs) = 
    case myReverse xs of
         Just list -> ...
         Nothing   -> ...
```

And of course, you need to decide what needs to be done in each of these cases, depending on what you want `myReverse` to do.

Also keep in mind that not *every* function needs to be recursive, so you can call the regular `reverse` from `myReverse` if you need it.

Comment: I've tried for a while and can't wrap my head around how to implement the recursion suggested in your coded section (I'm assuming it should supplant only the last line of vildric's code). Can you give me/us a hint?

Comment: The only way I could come up with to apply your coded section is with mappend, as zurgl mentioned, but then the case syntax would seem superfluous since you could write `myReverse (x:xs) = mappend (myReverse xs) (Just [x])`. Using the case syntax: `myReverse [] = Nothing; case myReverse xs of Nothing   -> Just [x]; otherwise -> mappend (myReverse xs) (Just [x])` ..Is there a way to implement your coded section without mappend?

Comment: You're not even using the value bound by the case!  In the `Just list ->` case, `list` is a value of type `[a]`, to which you can do as you please... for example `Just (list ++ [x])`.  In any case, this answer is "low level" and I would consider it a smell if it occurred in my code; I would generally prefer to use `mappend` as you suggested.  I just wanted to keep it nice and concrete for beginners.

Comment: It doesn't work, or at least I can't make it work. I toyed with all manner of expressions, including Just `(list ++ [x])`. Could you please show a working example without mappend?

Comment: @groovy maybe you can ask another SO question about it?

Comment: good idea. But if others can't make your suggestion work, I'm likely to ask you again :)

Comment: @groovy I figured I would answer it if others didn't ;-).  It's just hard to do this kind of thing in the comments -- I want to know where you got tripped up, what errors you encountered, etc.

Comment: I removed the question. Thanks again! It works! (As i tried it, it was not coming out of the infinite loop, but I cannot remember how I coded it.)

Answer (score 5):

As `[a]` is a **Monoid** define by,

```
instance Monoid [a] where
        mempty  = []
        mappend = (++)
```

Then `Maybe [a]` is also a **Monoid**,

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
    mempty = Nothing
    Nothing `mappend` m = m
    m `mappend` Nothing = m
    Just m1 `mappend` Just m2 = Just (m1 `mappend` m2)
```

Note the type constraint in the instance declaration which impose `a` to be a Monoid or else `Maybe a` won't.

We can then use mappend, `(<>)`, to chain our recursive call at the condition to transform the head of the list to a singleton.

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

myReverse :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
myReverse []     = Nothing
myReverse (x:xs) = myReverse xs <> Just [x]
```

Last note, the previous fold solution can be improve too.

```
>>> let mrev = foldl' (\x y -> Just [y] <> x ) Nothing
>>> mrev []
Nothing
>>> mrev "hello"
Just "olleh"
```

---

*Previous fold answer*

Knowing that reverse can be define using fold as follow,

```
>>> foldl' (flip (:)) [] [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

This can be rewritten as,

```
>>> foldl' (\x y -> y:x) [] [1..5]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

To adapt for Maybe type, we do the following transformation,

- The seed `[]` become `(Just [])`
- The anonymous function must now be apply inside Just, we use fmap to do it.

This lead us to,

```
>>> foldl' (\x y -> fmap (y:) x) (Just []) [1..5]
Just [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Finally,

```
mreverse xs | null xs = Nothing 
            | foldl' (\x y -> fmap (y:) x) (Just []) xs
```

Comment: Cool interpretation...what about the "Nothing" for `myReverse []`?

Comment: we can manage this case using pattern guard, `mreverse xs | null xs = Nothing | otherwise = foldl' (\x y -> fmap (y:) x) (Just []) xs`

Answer (score 1):

I thought of something along the lines of luqui's, except applying the Maybe at the end:

```
myReverse :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
myReverse ys
  | null (myReverse' ys) = Nothing
  | otherwise            = Just (myReverse' ys)
 where
   myReverse' []     = []
   myReverse' (x:xs) = myReverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Or, if you will,

```
myReverse ys | null (reverse ys) = Nothing
             | otherwise         = Just (reverse ys)
```

Comment: This will always return `Nothing` or throw an error because `otherwise = True`. Did you mean something more like `let reversed = myReverse' ys in if null reversed then Nothing else Just reversed`?

Comment: Oh, I was misreading the pattern as an expression. I’ve never thought to call a wildcard case `otherwise` because it would shadow `Prelude.otherwise`.